# Casting CustomError to ErrorType to NSError loses userInfo

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, foundation

Trying to cast a `CustomError` to compatible types (ErrorType, NSError) results in the user info dictionary being lost:

```
class CustomError: NSError {}

let error = CustomError(domain: "com.customerrorexample", code: 500, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "A great description"])
```

then

```
((error as ErrorType) as NSError).localizedDescription // "The operation couldn't be completed..."
```

However this will print the correct description:

```
((error as ErrorType) as! CustomError).localizedDescription // "A great description"
```

How come that `((CustomError as ErrorType) as NSError)` loses the userInfo dictionary? How can I work around it, knowing that my actual code will take an `ErrorType` as input, and print its `localizedDescription` - which should be accurate whatever the NSError subclass is?

#### Edit

See my own answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033365/646960. Still not an optimal solution, feel free to propose a better one.

Comment: Why does the title refer to CustomNSError when you don't seem to be using that protocol?

Comment: @MichaelTsai I meant `CustomError`, which is described in my code as just being a class extending `NSError`. Turns out that `CustomNSError` is now a SDK class, wasn't at the time I wrote this post (2015). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Cool. Thanks for clarifying. That should prevent confusion for people searching for the CustomNSError protocol now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like preventing the compiler magic that casts ErrorType to NSError works well:

```
((error as Any) as! NSError).localizedDescription // "A great description"
```

Comment: This worked for me. I added this as an extension. ```extension ErrorType {
    var userDescription: String {
        if let error = ((self as Any) as? NSError) where !error.localizedDescription.isEmpty {
            return error.localizedDescription
        } else {
            return "Something went wrong."
        }
    }
}```